# Bernoulli process of not-fixed probability p?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Here's a question that might be basic, but I want to understand what distribution(s) would result when the underlying Bernoulli trials' probability $p$ is not constant...?? I assume that it's not the Binomial, and that it depends on the law of variation of $p$. So, say that $p$ varies between [0,1] obeying certain probability distribution which applies in that range, i.e. Beta, Uniform, or some truncated version. Which are the resulting distributions, if any, for this underlying PDFs which represent $p$? 
Thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot more complicated and I doubt it even has a name.  Basically the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ in the probability mass function would go away and you'd have to consider each sequence of zeros and ones summing to $k$ separately.

Comment: Distribution of what, exactly?

Comment: Of some underlying process that changes its properties with time. I was wondering how this model can be modified to account for such a circumstance.

Comment: Beta-binomial distribution?

Comment: This one actually seems to be the one!, at least when p is unknown but Beta distributed, which can be made similar to a Normal if need be. According to Wiki: "the beta-binomial distribution is a family of discrete probability distributions ... arising when the probability of success in each of a fixed or known number of Bernoulli trials is either unknown or random. The beta-binomial distribution is the binomial distribution in which the probability of success at each trial is not fixed but random and follows the beta distribution." Thanks Christoph!!!

Comment: Sorry to ask, but if $p$ grows linearly with $t$, wouldn't $p$ go beyond and above 1 in a finite amount of time? Wouldn't you be looking for something more akin to a logistic regression on time? Like $\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \alpha + \beta \cdot t$ for instance?

Comment: Hi Marcelo, I guess you mean a way to model $p$? Your suggestion could work, but I was asking about any general variation of $p$ alwais in $[0-1]$.

Comment: If $p$ varies with time, then there is no "distribution" *per se.*

Comment: The exact distribution will be complex & will depend on how the Bernoulli trials are sampled over time, what the total duration is, how the parameter, p, changes with time, etc. Can you fill all of that in?  What does it mean for the "success probability p increases linearly"? If it were really linear, it would go out of bounds [0, 1] before long, which is nonsensical.

Comment: Hello @gung, I updated the question. Please feel free to interpret (and propose) the law of variation of $p$, in whatever ways that lead to a closed solution, or to no solution at all. Thanks!

Comment: Hi: You could impose a distribution on the underlying distribution which is think is related to hierarchical bayes modelling. But, in that case, the underlying parameter of the distribution of the distribution is not varying but just unknown so I'm not sure if this is what you'd want. As whuber said, if $p$ is truly changing, then I don't think one can call that a distribution.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen, you can't really say that. $p$ can't have a normal distribution, b/c it has to stay w/i [0,1] & the normal goes to infitinty in both directions. You're going to need to give a fully specified example. At present, this is essentially, 'if I had a number, what number would it be?'

Comment: Hi @mlofton; I changed the question slightly, suppose that p is represented by whatever distribution which is bounded in [0,1], either by default or truncated. So, provided that for p constant, the result is the binomial, what is the resulting distribution for the other cases?

Comment: Hi: It's been a long time since I've dealt with bayesian and I'm no expert. The idea is that you assume some distribution for $p$ say uniform. Then, you say that, given $p$, $X$, the rv,  is say binomial(n,p). Then, from there, you can ( hopefully ), derive the unconditional distribution for $X$. But that distribution of $X$ needs to be derived. Whether this is possible depends on whether the other distributions are "nice". If they're not nice, maybe you can use MCMC but this is  not my area so I don't want to say incorrect stuff. In fact, I hope what I already said is correct.